# what data type is the java class expecting for a webservice request?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans IDE and I'm creating a webservivce client from a wsdl file.

Netbeans has created all the classes and I've inserted the webservice reference to a jsp page and Netbeans has generated the following code:

```
<% 
try {
com.businessobjects.DataServicesServer service = new com.businessobjects.DataServicesServer();
com.businessobjects.RealTimeServices port = service.getRealTimeServices();
 // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
com.businessobjects.service.postcodelookup.input.PostcodeLookupRequest inputBody = null;
// TODO process result here
com.businessobjects.service.postcodelookup.output.PostcodeLookupReply result = port.postcodeLookup(inputBody);
out.println("Result = "+result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
// TODO handle custom exceptions here
}
%>
```

From this code I understand that I need to set a value for 'inputBody' (currently set as null by default) but I don't know what data type to use.

Here the code from PostcodeLookupReply.class

```
package com.businessobjects.service.postcodelookup.input;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


 /**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this    class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="postcode">
 *           &lt;simpleType>
 *             &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string">
 *               &lt;maxLength value="7"/>
 *             &lt;/restriction>
 *           &lt;/simpleType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
 "postcode"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "postcodeLookupRequest")
public class PostcodeLookupRequest {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String postcode;

/**
 * Gets the value of the postcode property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getPostcode() {
    return postcode;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the postcode property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setPostcode(String value) {
    this.postcode = value;
}

}
```

The value that need to be passed to 'inputBody' will be created from a parameter value from a URL string. I just need to know what and how to convert it so that it's accepted by the class.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do.t you refer your wsdl file? You can use soapui, to get input request format, make that request message in your code and provide it in inputBody.

Comment: The WSDL is referred to in com.businessobjects.DataServicesServer. Is that what your were asking?

Comment: Can you post the signature for

    RealTimeServices.postcodeLookup
?

Comment: Tonny - how do I do that?

Comment: user309039 - I've downloaded soapUI. Where do I find the input request format?

Comment: goto file->new soapui project,browse your wsdl file or provide wsdl url there, check create request message and click ok. Request message strutcure will be generated if no error encountered under operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a new PostcodeLookupRequest() with the setPostCode method called on that instance.

Comment: Pretty sure I tried this with no result. To confirm, are you saying:  com.businessobjects.service.postcodelookup.input.PostcodeLookupRequest req = new com.businessobjects.service.postcodelookup.input.PostcodeLookupRequest(); req.setPostcode("ABC");   com.businessobjects.service.postcodelookup.input.PostcodeLookupRequest inputBody = req;

Comment: Working code is:    
PostcodeLookupRequest pReq = new PostcodeLookupRequest();
pReq.setPostcode("A12ABC");
PostcodeLookupRequest inputBody = pReq;
PostcodeLookupReply pReply = postcodeLookup(inputBody);

Comment: PostcodeLookupRequest inputBody = pReq; - That line is pointless. But yes, that should work.